# Overlaping dates

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, lead

*Edit - No update rights.

I have the below tables: An id should be associated to one area only. There's overlap on TableB. Therefore John on 1/9/19 is associated to area East and MidEast.

Can I manipulate TableB to fix the overlapping?

So, the oldest row `enddate (1/9/19) would change to 1/7/19.`

There can be more than one day overlap.

`Lead` and or `Lag` be used here? Not sure where to start.

TableA

```
CustDate   id   Name
1/9/19      1   John
```

TableB

```
StartDate   EndDate      AREA
 1/1/2019    1/9/19      East
 1/8/2019    12/31/4000  Mideast
```

Example SQL

```
 ,CASE WHEN ENDDATE >
LEAD(STARTDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STARTDATE) 
THEN MIN(ENDDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) - interval '1' day
ELSE ENDATE
END END_DT2
```

Comment: What does `TableA` have to do with this question?

Comment: Correct. one could answer the question without referring to table A but added to visually show my issue of Name being associated to multiple areas..

Comment: Besides `StartDate, EndDate, AREA` isn't there a column like `id` referring to John's id in tableb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `Lead` and `Lag`

Something like below:

```
  ,CASE
   WHEN ENDDATE > LEAD(STARTDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STARTDATE) 
   THEN LEAD (STARTDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STARTDATE) -1
               ELSE ENDDATE
               END END_DT
```

Comment: If this is not an answer to your question, edit your question and put the code in it and then delete this post.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix `TableB` by updating `enddate`:

```
update tableb b
    set enddate = (select min(startdate) - interval '1' day
                   from tableb b2
                   where b2.startdate > b.startdate
                  );
```

Or, express this as a `select`:

```
select b.startdate,
       lead(b.startdate, 1, date '4000-12-31') over (order by b.startdate) - interval '1' day as enddate,
       b.area
from tableb b;
```